# JavaScript abstraction passing console.log in an argument

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hello StackOverflow whizzes!

I'm currently on Eloquent JavaScript book on the road to teaching myself JavaScript!

Currently I'm working abstracting a for loop action which is the code as followed...

```
function forEach(array, action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        action(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Then forEach is called with...

```
forEach(["Wampeter", "Foma", "Granfalloon"], print);
```

However instead of print I want to log it into the console, therefore i'd change print to console.log however I will get an error through for an illegal invocation.

Anybody got any ideas on why this is happening and how I might achieve this?

Cheers guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem will apply to any function that require the [context (this)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to be properly set up.
To fix this, you can bind 'this' :

```js
forEach(['foo', 'bar'], console.log.bind(console));
```

Hope this helps!